# Cap ligatures in Adobe Arno Pro won't compile

Tags: ligatures

Hi and best wishes for 2016.

I've got an issue with the 'RA' ligature.

The font I use – [Adobe Arno Pro](http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/files/2013/11/ArnoPro-Regular_GC.pdf) – contains a beautiful liason between the bottom serifs of capital R and A that used to complie just fine.
But after updating my MacTeX installation, LuaTeX rev. 39057 stumbles: `This can't happen (linebreak_tail).`

Here's the minimum (un)working example:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{Arno Pro}
\newcommand\allcapsspacing[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=7.5}#1}}
\begin{document}
{\Huge \allcapsspacing{FOOBRA}}\\[\baselineskip]
\end{document}
```

The code compiles well if I switch the font or lowercase `FOOBRA`.

Can you suggest a fix, please?

Comment: You should report such problems to the luaotfload bug tracker: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike, will do. This does look like a bug. But is LuaTeX to blame?

Comment: I can't say, I don't have the font. But my first suspect would be luaotfload. It has been updated lately and there were other errors regarding letter spacing. E.g. https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/310